# how to avoid caching when using mmap()

Tags: linux, caching, linux-kernel, zynq

I'm writing a driver in petalinux for a device in my FPGA and I have implemented the mmap function in order to control the device in the user space. My problem is that, also if I'm using

```
vma->vm_page_prot = pgprot_noncached(vma->vm_page_prot);
```

in the mmap function and `MAP_SHARED` flag in the user application, it seems that the cache is enabled.

The test I did is to write a value (say 5) to a specific register of my mmaped device that actually stores only the least significant bit of the data coming from the AXI bus. If I read immediately after the write operation, I expect to read 1 (this happened when using a bare metal application on Microblaze), instead I read 5. However, the value is correctly wrote in the register, because what has to happen....happens.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How exactly are you accessing (write/read) the mmap'd region in your code? Specifically, can you provide a code snippet of how you're writing/reading the specific register you're talking about?

Comment: In my application I'm using `address = mmap(NULL, PAGE_SIZE, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);` while when writing/reading from the mmaped region I'm using `*(unsigned int*)(address+REG_OFFSET) = 5` and `temp_var = *(unsigned int*)(address+REG_OFFSET)`.

Comment: is `address` declared as `volatile` ?

Comment: uhm...actually it isn't....I will try in one hour...

Comment: also I recommend you to use `memcpy(&temp_var, address + REG_OFFSET, sizeof(unsigned int))`. You should also use `inttypes.h`, such as `uint32_t` (or the type that reflects the size of the register) instead of `unsigned int`.

Comment: You should also rule out any latency problems (the time between you write and read the value, was it updated by the device in between?)

Comment: Thank you for all your valuable suggestions...ok, `volatile` fixes the thing (and it was a big mistake from me...). But now I wonder why also using `memcpy` (without `volatile`) the code behaves correctly. Which is the difference between `temp=*(addr)` and `memcpy(&temp, addr,...)` ?

Comment: You should look at the assembly your compiler generates. You may find that the value was simply stored in a (CPU) register and no additional memory access happened.

Comment: @Alessandro that (using memcpy() without `address` declared as `volatile`) is also prone to compiler optimizations and it's not granted to deliver the expected results. In your case, the compiler isn't performing optimizations over the `memcpy()`, that's why it's behaving as you expect. Using `volatile` basically will prevent the compiler from optimizing (or makes assumptions) over the contents of `address`, and that's what you really expect it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what was discussed in the question comments, the `address` pointer being assigned here:

```
address = mmap(NULL, PAGE_SIZE, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fd, 0);
```

wasn't declared with the type qualifier `volatile`, allowing the compiler to preform assumptions over it, leading to potential compile time optimizations over the read/write operations.